# how to check the browser history on local system using java

Tags: java, browser

I want to check last hour browser history on the local machine using a java program. So is there any way around to so that?

Thanks and regards,
Vivek Birdi.

Comment: This sounds like a spying attempt.

Comment: hi darioo.. this is not a spy attempt but the requirement of my project. The software will check on the system where it is installed and this will be listed in the features of the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably going to have to do a bit of checking for the individual browsers as they store the history data in different ways, and even in terms of the same browser there is going to be platform dependent code.

Firefox (perhaps the easiest browser to accomplish this task for) for instance stores the history in a sqlite3 file called places.sqlite, so by using the JDBC Sqlite driver you should be able to access it. (The format is fairly well documented and Sqlite on Java is as well).

For the others it is a matter of researching where and what format they store the history in and writing code to access it.

You're then going to have to build a table of all accesses in the last hour, because it is going to be impossible to know without probing what browser the user uses.

Comment: It is also quite possible that the on-disk history data is not completely up-to-date if the browser is still running.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Reese Moore, I need this thing in two more browsers, Internet explorer and Safari.